# How can i view the source code of my app on android studio

Tags: resources, android-source

So i have just finished my app on android studio and now want to find the source code file/s but can't seem to find it, i have searched for it in the androidstudioprojects folder but probably wasn't able to point it out (also side note, is the source code a single file or a number of files?) and must i decompile the apk and unzip it to be able to see the source code file. i would really appreciate your help on this one and thank you in advance.

I tried decompile the apk file obline with one of the decompiler sites but not sure of it worked, i have also tried doing the analyze apk in the studio, it brought me to the page of classes.dex and resources.arsc etc.